# PHP Form isn't Editing MySQL Table Data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a PHP form that displays a MySQL Table row's column data inside of the inputs. For example, each column is put into a seperate input's value. I did this because I want the user to be able to edit the column data for a specific row. The user should be able to edit one of the input values, hit the submit button, and the column data for that row in the MySQL table will be changed. Currently, when I hit submit, I get the error `Could not edit job position:`. This happens even if I leave the input values the same.

Here is a picture of the full PHP page:
[image]
More information: In the photo you can see that there is an edit and delete link for each table row. The table rows represent the MySQL Table rows. When an edit link is clicked, my PHP form appears at the bottom, with inputs for the title, description, model, make, year, and price column. These inputs contain the values of each column for that table row.

Here is my full PHP page's code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>GBM Trailer Service Ltd. ::: Used Units Management</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$dbLink = new mysqli('dacom', 'ksbm', 'Kiaer', 'kabm');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Up and Down Arrow Links: PHP Code

$conn = new mysqli('dsm', 'kam', 'Kfr', 'kcm');

// if an arrow link was clicked...
if ($_GET['dir'] && $_GET['id']) {
   // make GET vars easier to handle
   $dir = $_GET['dir'];
   // cast as int and couple with switch for sql injection prevention for $id
   $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
   // decide what row we're swapping based on $dir
   switch ($dir) {
      // if we're going up, swap is 1 less than id
      case 'up': 
         // make sure that there's a row above to swap
         $swap = ($id > 1)? $id-- : 1;
         break;
      // if we're going down, swap is 1 more than id
      case 'down':
         // find out what the highest row is
         $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM used_trailers";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die();
         $r = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
         $max = $r[0];
         // make sure that there's a row below to swap with
         $swap = ($id < $max)? $id++ : $max;
         break;
      // default value (sql injection prevention for $dir)
      default:
         $swap = $id;
   } // end switch $dir
   // swap the rows. Basic idea is to make $id=$swap and $swap=$id 
   $sql = "UPDATE used_trailers SET orderid = CASE orderid WHEN $id THEN $swap WHEN $swap THEN $id END WHERE orderid IN ($id, $swap)";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die;
} // end if GET  

// set a result order with a default (sql infection prevention for $sortby)
$sortby = ($_GET['sortby'] == 'title')? $_GET['sortby'] : 'orderid';

// Delete link: PHP Code

// delete from table
if ($_GET['del'] == 'true') {
   // cast id as int for security
   $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
   // delete row from table
   $sql = "DELETE FROM used_trailers WHERE orderid = '$id'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die();
   // select the info, ordering by usort
   $sql = "SELECT orderid, title FROM used_trailers ORDER BY orderid";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die();
   // initialize a counter for rewriting usort
   $job_pos_sortt = 1;
   // while there is info to be fetched...
   while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $job_poss = $r['orderid'];
      // update the usort number to the one in the next number
      $sql = "UPDATE used_trailers SET orderid = '$job_pos_sortt' WHERE title = '$job_poss'";
      $update = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die();
      // inc to next avail number
      $job_pos_sortt++;
   } // end while
} // end if del

// Connect to the database
$dbLink = new mysqli('da.com', 'am', 'aer', 'kabm');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Query for a list of all existing files
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM used_trailers ORDER BY orderid';
$result = $dbLink->query($sql);

// Check if it was successfull
if($result) {
    // Make sure there are some files in there
    if($result->num_rows == 0) {
        echo '<p>There are no files in the database</p>';
    }
    else {
        // Print the top of a table
        echo '<table width="100%" border="1">
                <tr valign="middle" align="center">';
            echo "<td>Order</td>";
            echo "<td>Title</td>";
            echo   '<td valign="middle"><b>Description</b></td>
                    <td valign="middle"><b>Model</b></td>
                    <td valign="middle"><b>Make</b></td>
                    <td valign="middle"><b>Year</b></td>
                    <td valign="middle"><b>Price</b></td>
                    <td valign="middle"><b>Photo 1</b></td>
                    <td valign="middle"><b>Photo 2</b></td>
                    <td valign="middle"><b>Photo 3</b></td>
                    <td valign="middle"><b>Photo 4</b></td>
                    <td valign="middle"><b>Photo 5</b></td>
                    <td valign="middle"><b>PDF</b></td>
                    <td valign="middle"><b>Edit/Delete</b></td>
                </tr>';

        // Print each file
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "
                <tr valign='middle' align='center'>
                   <td align = 'center' valign = 'center'><a style='color:black;' href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?dir=up&id={$row['orderid']}'>/\</a>
                    <a style='color:black;' href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?dir=down&id={$row['orderid']}'>\/</a></td>
                    <td valign='middle'>{$row['title']}</td>
                    <td valign='middle'>{$row['description']}</td>
                    <td valign='middle'>{$row['model']}</td>
                    <td valign='middle'>{$row['make']}</td>
                    <td valign='middle'>{$row['year']}</td>
                    <td valign='middle'>{$row['price']}</td>
                    <td valign='center'><img width=100 height=100 src=images/{$row['photo']}></td>
                    <td valign='center'><img width=100 height=100 src=images/{$row['photo1']}></td>
                    <td valign='center'><img width=100 height=100 src=images/{$row['photo2']}></td>
                    <td valign='center'><img width=100 height=100 src=images/{$row['photo3']}></td>
                    <td valign='center'><img width=100 height=100 src=images/{$row['photo4']}></td>
                    <td valign='center'><a target='_blank' href='downloadfile.php?id={$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</a></td>
                    <td align = 'center' valign = 'center'><b><a href='pdfget.php?orderid={$row['orderid']}' style='color:black;'>Edit</a> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?del=true&id={$row['orderid']}' style='color:black;' onclick='return show_confirm();'>Delete</a></b></td>
                </tr>";
        }

        // Close table
        echo '</table>';
    }

    // Free the result
    $result->free();
}
else
{
    echo 'Error! SQL query failed:';
    echo "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
}

// Close the mysql connection
$dbLink->close();
?>

<?php
if (isset($_GET["orderid"])) {
    $sn = (int)($_GET["orderid"]);
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$job_pos_sort = $_POST['orderid'];
$job_pos = $_POST['title'];
$job_pose = $_POST['description'];
$job_pose1 = $_POST['make'];
$job_pose2 = $_POST['model'];
$job_pose3 = $_POST['year'];
$job_pose4 = $_POST['price'];

$dbhost = 'daom';
$dbuser = 'keabm';
$dbpass = 'Kaer';
$dbname = 'keagbm';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE used_trailers SET title='$job_pos', description='$job_pose', make='$job_pose1', model='$job_pose2', year='$job_pose3', price='$job_pose4' WHERE orderid=$job_pos_sort";

$retval = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(! $retval )
{
  die(mysqli_error($conn) . "update failed");
}
echo "Edited job position successfully. <br />\n";
echo "Click <a style='color:black;' href='managecareers.php'>here</a> to refresh the page";

}
else
{
$job_posname = "SELECT title FROM used_trailers WHERE orderid = $sn";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $job_posname);
$array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$job_posname=stripslashes($array['title']);

$job_posname1 = "SELECT description FROM used_trailers WHERE orderid = $sn";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $job_posname1);
$array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$job_posname1=stripslashes($array['description']);

$job_posname2 = "SELECT make FROM used_trailers WHERE orderid = $sn";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $job_posname2);
$array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$job_posname2=stripslashes($array['make']);

$job_posname3 = "SELECT model FROM used_trailers WHERE orderid = $sn";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $job_posname3);
$array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$job_posname3=stripslashes($array['model']);

$job_posname4 = "SELECT year FROM used_trailers WHERE orderid = $sn";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $job_posname4);
$array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$job_posname4=stripslashes($array['year']);

$job_posname5 = "SELECT price FROM used_trailers WHERE orderid = $sn";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $job_posname5);
$array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$job_posname5=stripslashes($array['price']);
?>

<div align="center">
<p style="position:relative; left:-11px;">Edit Job Position</p>
<form method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td><input name="job_pos_sort" type="hidden" id="job_pos_sort" value="<?php echo $sn;?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100" style="color:white;">Job Position:</td>
<td><input name="job_pos" type="text" id="job_pos" value="<?php echo $job_posname;?>"><span id="measure"></span></td>
<td><input name="description" type="text" id="description" value="<?php echo $job_posname1;?>"></td>
<td><input name="make" type="text" id="make" value="<?php echo $job_posname2;?>"></td>
<td><input name="model" type="text" id="model" value="<?php echo $job_posname3;?>"></td>
<td><input name="year" type="text" id="year" value="<?php echo $job_posname4;?>"></td>
<td><input name="price" type="text" id="price" value="<?php echo $job_posname5;?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Edit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
}
else {
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't know it it's really causing the problem, but you forgot to set the single quotes in the SQL query. So it should be title='$job_pos' for example. You also forgot that in the later queries, but for some reason did it in one of the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the data in quotes in your query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE used_trailers SET title='$job_pos', description='$job_pose', make='$job_pose1', model='$job_pose2', year='$job_pose3', price='$job_pose4' WHERE orderid=$job_pos_sort";
```

Also, you should escape any database parameters from your input or they will break your query - `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for mySQL or `pg_escape_string()` for Postgres:

```
$job_pos_sort = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['orderid']);
$job_pos = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$job_pose = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
$job_pose1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['make']);
$job_pose2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['model']);
$job_pose3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
$job_pose4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I have updated the code in my question to what I currently have. I do not want to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` because I am going to be converting this code from Mysqli to MSSQL once I get it functioning properly.

Comment: Nice SQL injection vulnerability you've got there

Comment: It looks like `$conn` might not be a valid database connection - when it gets created, it's not being tested the way `$dbLink` is. Do you mean to use two different databases and connections?

Comment: @FredWillmore I added the $conn to my code, and edited the error message a bit. I do not mean to use different databases, although I do mean to have $dbLink and $conn. I am now getting the error message `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1update failed` when I hit the submit button. I have also edited the code in my question to what I currently have.

Comment: try echoing the value of `$sql` to the screen so you can see what query it's trying to run. I suspect maybe it's not getting a value for `$job_pos_sort` though I can't know without seeing the query

Comment: Ah, you were right, it wasn't getting a value for $title, either. Thank you, I got it working!